# Magento 2.3.3 PayPal problem while checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.3.3

I'm making a payment by PayPal as a customer (express & Standard) in IWD OPC 
and I getting this error.
This happened in my both sites after the 2.3.3 updated
[image]

`[2019-10-16 07:11:40] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5da6b02296f14; Message: Property "DisableTmpl" does not have accessor method "getDisableTmpl" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5da6b02296f14; Message: Property \"DisableTmpl\" does not have accessor method \"getDisableTmpl\" in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\PaymentInterface\". at /home/332092.cloudwaysapps.com/wvrgznubmd/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"DisableTmpl\" does not have accessor method \"getDisableTmpl\" in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\PaymentInterface\". at /home/332092.cloudwaysapps.com/wvrgznubmd/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []`

Appreciate any help
Thanks, 
Kobi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the below js file and update as per given below then do compilation and test.

**File path:** vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js

**Overwrite to:** app/design/frontend/{your theme}/{theme name}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js

**Old:**

```
define([
    '../model/quote'
], function (quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (paymentMethod) {
        if (paymentMethod) {
            paymentMethod.__disableTmpl = {
                title: true
            };
        }
        quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);
    };
});
```

**New:**

```
 define([
    '../model/quote'
], function (quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (paymentMethod) {
        /*if (paymentMethod) {
            paymentMethod.__disableTmpl = {
                title: true
            };
        }*/
        quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);
    };
});
```

Then do the compilation, then it will work.

Reference [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24986).

Comment: I have implement your solution but PayPal payflow Pro is still not working.

Comment: Our problem went away with this fix. As stated in the other solution here you should put the fix to your theme folder app/design/frontend/{your theme}/{theme name}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js

Comment: any disadvantage of commenting above code ?

Answer (score 3):

It's always no good to modify the core file. It'd be better to override it by copying the file to your theme and put it in Magento_Checkout directory . For example copy the file from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js` to `app/design/frontend/{your theme}/{theme name}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js`.
Then modify the copied file like ManiMaran A said.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem at the moment, just using stock paypal express module. And we're getting this error..

> Property "DisableTmpl" does not have accessor method "getDisableTmpl"
>   in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface".

In the IWD Onepage checkout, it doen't matter if i disable it or not.. it's very frustrating.. we're also working with a VES Theme

We just updated to Magento version 2.2.11

Comment: did you found any solution for this