# Magento 2.3.3 PayPal payflow pro problem while checkout

Tags: paypal, magento2.3.3, credit-card, paypal-payflow-pro

I have upgraded my store to latest magento version 2.3.3. I have started testing and found one issue on checkout. I have tried placing order through paypal payflow Pro(credit card payment method) and I couldn't place order successfully. However, when I have tried paying thorough PayPal Express then order got placed successfully but using payflow Pro I couldn't place order.

Any one have facing this type of issue or any one know the solution of this issue?

Comment: Did you check error from exception log, system.log?

Comment: Yes @sohel I have checked error log and also follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292776/magento-2-3-3-paypal-problem-while-checkout this post. But paypal payflow is not working.

Comment: Please post your error so i can help to resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

The issue was fixed by Magento team. The fix was delivered into magento/magento2:2.4-develop branch(es).
Related commit(s):

abdb45844fd3862a8a2f852fb34d35cc0e958829
8ed20d151301484271b03755006e203e80ef76eb
8211eb79022e2167dad38349c63bb9c36279e34d
6d6af36f4fb31dfe7f585061d34332ed0819fe1a
45b9e193ddd8a413cb041976de6f1d9da5f53d5f
The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.4.0 release.

Comment: Link is not answer if link is expired. Please add content of answer

Answer (score 0):

I also had PayFlow issues, the checkout page would never finish loading, never generate an error, paypal Auth was fine, just no transaction.

It was the store switcher adding information to the redirect URL

paypal/transparent/redirect/

in the store switcher is an option for pages that should not have the information added to the URL.

Adding paypal/* was all it took, usually you will see checkout/* and a few other paths.

Hope this helps others that are having issues with Payflow never completing, never generating an error.